# ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)- While connecting to Redis through Jedis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to connect to redis server through Jedis client, but I am getting following exception and stack trace while connecting -

org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:204)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:348)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:129)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:92)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:79)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:194)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:169)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:91)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.get(DefaultHashOperations.java:49)
            at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor122.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
        Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
            at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53)
            at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226)
            at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:16)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:194)
            ... 24 more
        Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
            at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:207)
            at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:93)
            at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1767)
            at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:106)
            at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:888)
            at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:432)
            at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361)
            at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49)
            ... 27 more
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
            at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
            at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
            at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
            at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:184)

This is the configuration of Jedis Pool -

```
@Bean
    public JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig() {
        JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(5000);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(8);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMinIdle(1);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(10);
        return jedisPoolConfig;
    }

@Bean
public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        factory.setPoolConfig(jedisPoolConfig());
        factory.setShardInfo(shardInfo());
        factory.setHostName(serviceConfiguration.REDIS_HOST_NAME);
        factory.setPort(serviceConfiguration.REDIS_PORT);
        factory.setUsePool(true);
        return factory;
}
```

Please suggest, what should be changed or tried in order to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured your connection factory bean properly as well

```
 @Bean
  public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {

    RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("server", 6379);
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(config);
  }
```

Comment: I have added the code for connection factory also, please check, it looks correct to me.

Comment: The stacktrace points to a socket connection exception. I would first try to make sure that connection parameters are all correct by removing the pooling. Step by step.

Comment: This is the same configuration getting used by multiple components, some are able to connect to Redis, some are not..